# Windows XP login using Radius authentication

Tags: windows, radius

I would like to use existing Radius server to provide AAA for users which are logging to a Windows XP machine.
Cisco can use Radius, Linux (via PAM) as well, is it possible for Windows XP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I no experience with it but a quick Google search showed up pGina, it is a module that allows you to use alternate sources for authentication including radius.

- http://www.pgina.org/
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=330803&seqNum=2

Comment: pGina is about the only option out there. Setting up Samba or AD is a more sensible and scalable option however.